# Purging technique for Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, nosql

I am a newbie in Amazon Dynamodb world with strong background from relation database world :-p

I am writing a service using AWS lambda functionality that migrates the data from dynamodb to RedShift for analytics purpose. My aim is to keep only active data of say 1 month in dynamodb and then purge it periodically.

I researched a lot but could not find a precise purging technique for Amazon dynamodb that will avoid full table scan.

Also, I want to perform delete based on the Range key attribute which is a timestamp attribute.

Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: use query instead of scan

Comment: maybe try using ttl property and it will get deleted after x days.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the easiest and most cost-effective way to handle this job is to create a new table each month, and remove complete old tables when time passes and you are done crunching them.

If you can make your use case use a TABLE-MMYYYY it would help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you Chen. That was the option I thought of earlier but problem is that my system can not stop populating data in table while it is being deleted and recreated. I am continuously writing data to table say 3000-5000 items per hour

Comment: The way i look at it you create the table the day before a month start and then the writes are writing data to the correct table by current month. Then a few days thru the month, once you're done crunching last-month data you can delete the whole table